# Is it possible to return an address of a const pointer argument in a function without const qualifier without a warning while -Wall is activated?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Well, the question is mostly above. The only things I could add are that I've tried `str+i` and `&(str[i])` and both gave me a `discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type` warning.

Or is there another way to resemble `strstr` and `strchr`(which both don't have a const qualifier in their C version) without a warning?

Comment: You can do that by casting, but you shouldn't to that because it may be dangerous.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demomstrating the warnings/errors you want to discuss.

Comment: The answer I provided works in both GCC 10.2 and Clang 11.0.0 without warning when `-Wall` is used, per [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PMEoTY). However, in the future, when asking about a compiler-specific switch like `-Wall` and associated behavior, **state the compiler and its version** in the question. When working with computers, be detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cast to tell the compiler your conversion is intentional:

```
char *foo(const char *p)
{
    return (char *) p;
}
```

Note: Conversions that remove qualifiers are defined by the C standard when they are converting the pointer back to a type it originally had, per C 2018 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer…

Thus, if some `char *` pointer `x` has been converted to `const char *x`, then converting it back to `char *` yields the original value.

If the pointer was not originally unqualified, then converting it to an unqualified type is, in general, not fully defined by the C standard. The standard tells us we can convert the result back to its original type to get the original value, but it does not tell us we can use the result for anything else. For example:

```
const int i;
const int *x = &i;  // Defined, x points to i.
int *p = (int *) x; // Defined, p is a pointer that can be converted back to "const int *".
printf("%d\n", *p); // Not defined, value of p is not defined for “normal” use.
const int *y = p;   // Defined, produces y such that y == x and y == &i.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I added the `gcc`-tag above!

Comment: I would not say "too" much. Thanks for adding it. I was hoping for something of a wise recommendation to keep in mind that a well-placed `const` is a desirable protection. And that any `T* func(const T*)` could be unwisely used in a way to remove the desired protection of (probably) wisely applied `const`. Admittedly, lots of "could" in there....

Comment: @EricPostpischil, actually for me the example is worth than answer, I know I can cast `const x*`  into `x*` , but don't know its specified in standard